# How to use Group By with Join and Min in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, join, group-by, entity-framework-6

I have two tables.

Order:

- ID
- ProductID
- DeliveryDate

Product:

- ID
- Name
- Description

I want to get the list of all product with earliest delivery date.

I am getting correct data by using following sql.
This gives me list of all products with earliest delivery date.

```
SELECT 
    p.Name, p.Description, min(o.DeliveryDate)
FROM Product p
JOIN Order o
On o.ProductID = p.ID
Group By p.ID;
```

I have tried to write it using Linq but something is missing.
I am not able to identify how can I write this query.

I have tried out relative stack overflow solutions but not helped in my case.

My Linq is :

```
await (from p in dbContext.Product
  join o in dbContext.Order
  on o.ProductID equals p.ID
  select new
  {
      p.ID,
      p.Name,
      p.Description,
      o.DeliveryDate
  }).GroupBy(g => g.ID).ToListAsync();
```

It gives me data after join and group by. Where should I put Min in the Linq to get the Earliest DeliveryDate for the Product?

Comment: Is your LINQ code correct: you are joining Person and Order table?

Comment: Shit!! Its my bad. I have edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have a navigation property `Product.Orders`. If not, it's highly recommended to add it to your code. Having that property, this will achieve what you want:

```
from p in dbContext.Product
select new
{
    p.ID,
    p.Name,
    p.Description,
    MinDeliveryDate = (DateTime?)o.Orders.Min(o => o.DeliveryDate)
}
```

The cast to `DateTime?` is to prevent exceptions when products don't have orders.

If for some reason you don't have the navigation property and *really* can't add it at the moment you can use:

```
from p in dbContext.Product
select new
{
    p.ID,
    p.Name,
    p.Description,
    MinDeliveryDate = (DateTime?)dbContext.Order
                                          .Where(o => o.ProductID == p.ID)
                                          .Min(o => o.DeliveryDate)
}
```

Note that by starting the query at `Product` and not joining with `Order` you don't need the grouping any more.

Answer (score 1):

I used some classes to stand in for the database, but does this work?

```
class Product
{
  public int ID;
  public string Name;
  public string Description;
}

class Order
{
  public int ProductID;
  public DateTime DeliveryDate;
}

class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     Product[] proTestData = new Product[]
     {
        new Product() {ID=1, Name="Widget", Description="Banded bulbous snarfblat"},
        new Product() {ID=2, Name="Gadget", Description="Hitchhiker's guide to the galaxy"}
     };
     Order[] ordTestData = new Order[]
     {
        new Order() {ProductID=1, DeliveryDate=new DateTime(2017,12,14)},
        new Order() {ProductID=1, DeliveryDate=new DateTime(2017,12,20)},
        new Order() {ProductID=2, DeliveryDate=new DateTime(2017,12,23)},
        new Order() {ProductID=2, DeliveryDate=new DateTime(2017,12,22)},
        new Order() {ProductID=2, DeliveryDate=new DateTime(2017,12,21)},
        new Order() {ProductID=1, DeliveryDate=new DateTime(2017,12,18)}
     };

     var rows =
        (from p in proTestData
         join o in ordTestData
         on p.ID equals o.ProductID
         group o.DeliveryDate by p into grp
         select new {
            grp.Key.ID,
            grp.Key.Name,
            grp.Key.Description,
            minDate = grp.Min()}
        ).ToList();

     foreach (var row in rows)
     {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", row.Name, row.minDate);
     }
  }
}
```

The output is

```
Widget: 12/14/2017 12:00:00 AM
Gadget: 12/21/2017 12:00:00 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to order your groups you can use the "OrderBy" linq method.

Apply the following after the .GroupBy()

```
.OrderBy(group => group.First().DeliveryDate).ToListAsync();
```